# Getting the content from a RichText Control and send it via email

Tags: xpages

I have an XPage with a RichText control and I need to grab the content of it and send it via email.

I have it working by using `getComponent("rtfQuestion").getValue();`
and appending it to my HTML email:

```
var body = memo.createMIMEEntity();
var stream = session.createStream();


var url =  context.getUrl();
url.removeAllParameters();

msg = "The response linked below has been submitted.<br/><br/>"
var info = "Please click <a href='" + url.toString()+ "?documentId=" + doc.getDocument().getUniversalID() + "&action=openDocument"; 
info = info + "'>here</a> to view the new response." + "<br/><br/><fieldset><legend>Answered by " + @Name("[CN]",doc.getItemValueString("Originator")) + "</legend>" + getComponent("rtfQuestion").getValue() + "</fieldset>";

// Set content of Body field as MIME type           
stream.writeText(info);
body.setContentFromText(stream, "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1", 0);    

memo.send();
```

The problem I have is when user adds an Image using the "Insert Image" action from toolbar then the MIME Content-Type is "Content-Type: multipart/related" and image(s) are not been sent.

What could be the best way of getting the RichText content and send it via email?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

This is what I get from `getComponent("rtfQuestion").getValue()`:

[image]

This is the Body content from received email:

```
Field Name: Body
Data Type: MIME Part
Data Length: 977 bytes
Seq Num: 1
Dup Item ID: 0
Field Flags: SIGN SEAL 

"MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Please click <a href='http://tristan.corp.teradyne.com/applications/ask-b30.nsf/xResponse.xsp?documentId=056C62166F3A8B3E85257D490070264C&action=openDocument'>here</a> to view the new response.<br/><br/><fieldset><legend>Answered by Notes Dev1</legend><p dir="ltr">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quot mollis utamur ius ad, rebum timeam oporteat sea ea. Mea alii iriure at, ne tale probatus usu. Sonet consulatu dignissim ad per. Ne munere doming vim, ad sale everti voluptaria has.</p>
<p dir="ltr">
 Labore ceteros facilisi est in. His et regione phaedrum. Eam apeirian phaedrum vituperatoribus in, ei sea sint latine nominavi, est in rebum iisque nostrum. Utinam impedit ea sit, his cu agam probatus deserun</p>
<p dir="ltr">
 <img alt="" src="/applications/ask-b30.nsf/xsp/.ibmmodres/persistence/DominoDoc-18E2-Content/1.PNG" style="width: 249px; height: 172px;"></img></p></fieldset>"
```

Comment: can you add the sample code you get from the getComponent() call.... AND I strongly advise against using getComponent(). Bind the field to something (a scoped variable or a bean)

Comment: @stwissel, I added what I get from getComponent(). Also the RichText Control is already binded to a datasource field called Content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the emailBean by Tony McGuckin instead:
http://openntf.org/s/emailbean-send-dominodocument-html-emails-cw-embedded-images-attachments-custom-headerfooter

Comment: I'll take a look at this one.

Comment: afaik Tony's bean doesn't extract the RT images from the HTML source (?)

Comment: It does extract images from the source document.